# How to build url in smarty template?

Tags: php, templates, smarty

In template I have two strings which I want to combine in one.

```
{assign var="bigUrl" value="Search?searchFor=Member&{$searchUrl}"}
```

To be able to use variable `{$bigUrl}` below in template, like this:

```
<a href={$bigUrl}>Link</a>
```

When I write mentioned assignment smarty compiler report error:

```
syntax error: invalid attribute name: '='
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use braces inside smarty tags. Just remove them:

```
{assign var="bigUrl" value="Search?searchFor=Member&$searchUrl"}
```

Or use [`cat`](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.modifier.cat.php) filter:

```
{$bigUrl|cat:$searchUrl}
```

Comment: the first option didn't work for me. I had to go with a variation of the second: [{assign var="left" value="<a href=\"/index.php?cl="|cat:$prev|cat:"\">back</a>"}]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is it, but in the [**Smarty manual**](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.custom.functions.php#language.function.assign) all {assign}s are in single quotes. The error message would make sense if those don't work.

Can you try replacing the double quotes?